# How do I add a tab to the Sale Order Admin Page?

Tags: magento

I want to add a custom tab to the order page in the admin of magento.  Is there a way to do this with a simple override?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you know how to do a module, here are the steps you need to perform:

1. **layout update**: in your admin's xml layout file you want to "listening" to the admin's order view rendering handle and add your tab:

   ```
   <layout>
       <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
           <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
               <action method="addTab"><name>the_name_of_your_tab</name><block>the_block_alias_of_your_module/path_to_your_tab_file</block></action>
           </reference>
       </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
   </layout>
   ```
2. **the tab file**: I generally try to respect Magento's folder structure, so this file would be in **app/code/local-or-community/YourNamespace/YourModule/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Tab/File.php** and will have at least:

   ```
   <?php
   class YourNamespace_YourModule_Block_Adminhtml_Order_View_Tab_File
       extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
       implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
   {
       protected $_chat = null;

       protected function _construct()
       {
           parent::_construct();
           $this->setTemplate('yourmodule/order/view/tab/file.phtml');
       }

       public function getTabLabel() {
           return $this->__('Tab label');
       }

       public function getTabTitle() {
           return $this->__('Tab title');
       }

       public function canShowTab() {
           return true;
       }

       public function isHidden() {
           return false;
       }

       public function getOrder(){
           return Mage::registry('current_order');
       }
   ```
3. **The .phtml file**, which has to respect the path you specified in the block's  __construct(), and should hace something like:

   ```
   <div class="entry-edit">
       <div class="entry-edit-head">
           <h4><?php echo $this->__('a title'); ?></h4>
       </div>
       <div class="fieldset fieldset-wide">
           the content you want to show
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Hope That Helps