# How to rewrite or add custom tab to the sales order view?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, orders, ecommerce-sales

I want to add custom tab to sales order view page. I have tried the following code but nothing has happened.

- [How do I add a tab to the Sale Order Admin Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7084786)
- [Custom tab on sales order view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16789216)

My `module.xml` code is below:

```
 <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab"><name>my_tab</name><block>mymodule/Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Tabs</block></action>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

And my block class is:

```
class Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Tabs  extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Abstract
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
     Mage::Log("Fraud created");
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve order model instance
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve source model instance
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->getOrder();
    }


    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return Mage::helper('sales')->__('Fraud Detection');
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return Mage::helper('sales')->__('Fraud Detection');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any error in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by extending/overriding `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tabs`:

```
$this->addTab('testing', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('my_tab'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('my_tab'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('your/block_name')->toHtml(),
        ));
```

Comment: you need to add these lines in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tabs class

Comment: but i don't want to change core files.Any alternative will be appreciated.

Comment: there is no _beforeToHtml method to add your code mentioned above.