# Adding new Tab to Order View page not displaying in Magento

Tags: php, magento, adminhtml

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * MageWorx
 * Admin Order Editor extension
 *
 * @category   MageWorx
 * @package    MageWorx_OrdersEdit
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2015 MageWorx (http://www.mageworx.com/)
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MageWorx_OrdersEdit after="Mage_Adminhtml">MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Adminhtml</MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>

        <events>
            <sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item>
                <observers>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit_convert_order_item_to_quote_item>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                        <method>convertOrderItemToQuoteItem</method>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit_convert_order_item_to_quote_item>
                </observers>
            </sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item>
            <sales_convert_order_to_quote>
                <observers>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit_convert_order_to_quote>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                        <method>convertOrderToQuote</method>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit_convert_order_to_quote>
                </observers>
            </sales_convert_order_to_quote>            
            <sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
                <observers>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit_quote_collect_totals_after>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                        <method>quoteCollectTotalsAfter</method>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit_quote_collect_totals_after>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
            <adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data>
                <observers>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit_order_create_process_data>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                        <method>orderCreateProcessData</method>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit_order_create_process_data>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data>
            <core_collection_abstract_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <amflags>
                        <type>disabled</type>
                    </amflags>
                </observers>
            </core_collection_abstract_load_before>
        </events>

        <blocks>
            <mageworx_ordersedit>
                <class>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Block</class>
            </mageworx_ordersedit>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_view>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
                </rewrite>                
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <sales_mysql4>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_status_history_collection>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Resource_Order_Status_History_Collection</order_status_history_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </sales_mysql4>
            <salesrule>
                <rewrite>                    
                    <quote_discount>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_SalesRule_Quote_Discount</quote_discount>
                </rewrite>
            </salesrule>
            <payment>
                <rewrite>
                    <method_ccsave>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Payment_Method_Ccsave</method_ccsave>
                </rewrite>
            </payment>
            <paypal>
                <rewrite>
                    <payflowpro>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Paypal_Payflowpro</payflowpro>
                    <direct>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Paypal_Direct</direct>
                    <api_nvp>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Paypal_Api_Nvp</api_nvp>
                </rewrite>
            </paypal>
            <paygate>
                <rewrite>
                    <authorizenet>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Paygate_Authorizenet</authorizenet>
                </rewrite>
            </paygate>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_payment>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Sales_Order_Payment</order_payment>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
            <ordertags>
                <rewrite>
                    <observer>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_AwOrdertags_Observer</observer>
                </rewrite>
            </ordertags>

            <mageworx_ordersedit>
                <class>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mageworx_ordersedit_resource</resourceModel>
            </mageworx_ordersedit>

            <mageworx_ordersedit_resource>
                <class>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <upload_files>
                        <table>mageworx_ordersedit_upload_files</table>
                    </upload_files>                    
                </entities>
            </mageworx_ordersedit_resource>
        </models>

        <helpers>
            <mageworx_ordersedit>
                <class>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Helper</class>
            </mageworx_ordersedit>
        </helpers>

        <resources>
            <mageworx_ordersedit_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MageWorx_OrdersEdit</module>
                    <class>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mageworx_ordersedit_setup>
            <mageworx_ordersedit_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mageworx_ordersedit_write>
            <mageworx_ordersedit_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mageworx_ordersedit_read>
        </resources>

        <template>
            <email>               
               <mageworx_ordersedit_email_order_comment_template translate="label" module="mageworx_ordersedit">
                   <label>Order Edit</label>
                   <file>mageworx/ordersedit/mageworx_order_edited.html</file>
                   <type>html</type>
               </mageworx_ordersedit_email_order_comment_template>
               <mageworx_ordersedit_email_order_comment_guest_template translate="label" module="mageworx_ordersedit">
                   <label>Order Edit for Guest</label>
                   <file>mageworx/ordersedit/mageworx_order_edited_guest.html</file>
                   <type>html</type>
               </mageworx_ordersedit_email_order_comment_guest_template>
            </email>
        </template>

        <sales>            
           <order_invoice>
                <totals>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/sales_order_invoice_total</class>
                        <after>tax,grand_total</after>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit>
                    <subtotal>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/sales_order_invoice_subtotal</class>
                    </subtotal>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit_shipping>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/sales_order_invoice_shipping</class>
                        <after>shipping</after>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit_shipping>
                </totals>
            </order_invoice>       
        </sales>
    </global>

    <adminhtml>        
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mageworx_ordersedit>
                    <file>mageworx_ordersedit.xml</file>
                </mageworx_ordersedit>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
                <observers>
                    <mw_add_coupon_block>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                        <method>insertCouponBlock</method>
                    </mw_add_coupon_block>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
        </events>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
                    <files>
                        <default>MageWorx_OrdersEdit.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>

    <default>
        <mageworx_ordersmanagement>
            <ordersedit>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <enable_shipping_price_edition>1</enable_shipping_price_edition>
                <show_thumbnails>1</show_thumbnails>
                <thumbnail_height>50</thumbnail_height>
                <send_update_email>0</send_update_email>
                <hide_edit_button>1</hide_edit_button>
                <show_all_states_in_history>0</show_all_states_in_history>
            </ordersedit>
        </mageworx_ordersmanagement>
    </default>

</config>
```

Here is my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * MageWorx
 * Admin Order Editor extension
 *
 * @category   MageWorx
 * @package    MageWorx_OrdersEdit
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2015 MageWorx (http://www.mageworx.com/)
 */
-->
<layout>    
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>

        <reference name="avans_tabs">
            <action method="addTab"><name>avans_tab</name><block>mageworx_ordersedit/adminhtml_order_view_tab_avans</block></action>
        </reference>    

    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>

    <mageworx_ordersedit_order_history>
        <block type="mageworx_ordersedit/adminhtml_sales_order_history" name="order_history" template="mageworx/ordersedit/sales-order-view-history.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
    </mageworx_ordersedit_order_history>

    <adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_addcomment>
        <update handle="mageworx_ordersedit_order_history" />
    </adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_addcomment>

    <adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_deletehistory>
        <update handle="mageworx_ordersedit_order_history" />
    </adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_deletehistory>

    <adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_saveeditcomment>
        <update handle="mageworx_ordersedit_order_history" />
    </adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_saveeditcomment>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
        <reference name="invoice_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="ordersedit" template="mageworx/ordersedit/invoice_totals.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
</layout>
```

Here is my: `/MageWorx/OrdersEdit/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Tab/Avans.php`:

```
<?php
class MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Block_Adminhtml_Order_View_Tab_Avans
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    protected $_chat = null;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('ordersedit/order/view/tab/avans.phtml');
    }

    public function getTabLabel() {
        return $this->__('Tab label');
    }

    public function getTabTitle() {
        return $this->__('Tab title');
    }

    public function canShowTab() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden() {
        return false;
    }

    public function getOrder(){
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }
```

Here is my: `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mageworx/ordersedit/order/view/tab/avans.phtml`:

```
<div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4><?php echo $this->__('Hello its me!'); ?></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset fieldset-wide">
        the content you want to show
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add new custom tab to the order view page in the admin panel but nothing appears.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited here is full tutorial that will help you .

Comment: Pro tips for posting: (1) the community prefers titles in natural English, rather than in the form `tag/tag - problem`. This has been covered a few times on Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow. (2) There is no need to put `Please help me out` in every question - that you need help is implicit, and this rather sounds like begging. Keep it succinct! (3) Four questions in eight hours might be a bit much, and it may be worth slowing down.